# Symfony redirect with request

Tags: symfony, url, redirect, request

I want to redirect and send my request to another route but this method is not working.

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
    'admin_platform_create', 
    array('request' => $request)
 ));
```

When I arrive into admin_platform_create it doesn't pass that if

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {    
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
            {
```

Though this is working,

```
  return $this->forward('AdminPlatformBundle:Manage:edit',
    array('request' => $request));
```

It is not what I need as it is not writing the new URL.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to pass the Request object as an arguments ? The `Request` object represents the current request.

Comment: Browsers follow a redirect by issuing a _GET_ request for the new location – so you can’t expect to have access to any POST data afterwards. (As a workaround, you could possibly try and store the received POST data into the session, redirect, and then at the target read the data from the session again. Although for large requests this might have performance implications.)

Comment: If I don't pass the Request object as an argument I get this:
Controller "Admin\PlatformBundle\Controller\ManageController::createAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

Comment: @Hewyn CBroe already answered your question, after you redirect to the new route 'admin_platform_create' you are now sending a GET request, therefore `$request->getMethod() == 'POST'` will always be false and you will never enter that block of code doing so.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Symfony 2.6 or later, you can do it:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('route', [
    'request' => $request
], 307);
```

Comment: It works. 307 code preserves the request method and allows to have a new POST request with same parameters.